# Bootstrap tooltip on hover with link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, hover, tooltip

I wish to place a bootstrap tooltip on an `<i>` element to be shown on hover.

I realize that I need the following attributes for this:

```
data-html="true" data-trigger="hover"
```

However, the problem with this is that if I include an anchor tag (`<a>`) in the `title` attribute, then the user has no way to actually click on it (once the user takes his mouse off of the `<i>` element, the tooltip disappears).

Is there a way to do this in bootstrap? For example, is there a way to have the tooltip remain visible as long as the user keeps his mouse on the actual tooltip itself (ie: a mouse over the `<i>` element shows the tooltip and it remains visible so long as the user's mouse is on the `<i>` element **or** the shown tooltip box).

Update: If possible, I'd like to do this without custom javascript (ie: via Bootstrap library).

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/WojtekKruszewski/Zf3m7/22/) is what you want?

Comment: Hey, yeah, that looks pretty clean, thanks. I was wondering if there is a way to do it without custom js. I.e. only with Bootstrap classes/attributes.